# Error in designing a layout with textview in android

Tags: android

I am developing in android application in which i have to make a layout involving a spinner and textview.I am having problem.that the textview is not clickable.I have given a background to each of textview.Can anyone guide me how to make this..

Below is the screenshot
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/bc2a1

Below is the code of xml
http://pastebin.com/Y1Dsq4B1

Thanks in advance
Tushar Sahni

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure all views are clickable.

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.text, null);
TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblText);
t.setText(text);
t.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ public void onClick(View v) {
    // do something
}});
return v;
```

Comment: have u seen my xml and the screenshot...?? do i need to change in xml ??

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to change the names of the TextViews in your layout xml so they are not all the same. Right now they are all `text_section`. Then you need to add code in your activity that looks like bellow for each TextView:

```
TextView selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_selection); //declares the TextView
selection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Code to execute when TextView is pressed goes here
            }

        });
```